# Altering Databases in production without losing data

Tags: php, mysql, google-app-engine, google-cloud-sql

I have a web app that allows people to manage a set of users and lessons in a database. This database structure is replicated for each subscriber using the web app and they populate it with their data. For example:

```
Subscriber 1 DB
  user table
    userID, name, age, etc 
  lesson table
    lessonID, start, end, location, etc

Subscriber 2 DB
  user table
    userID, name, age, etc 
  lesson table
    lessonID, start, end, location, etc
```

In the future, I will of course have to roll out changes to these databases as new features are added. How would I go about updating the database structure over all the databases?

I know how to add an extra column:

```
ALTER TABLE user ADD COLUMN address VARCHAR DEFAULT 0;
```

but how do I get it apply to all the databases? Is there a way to do this in MYSQL workbench?

This app uses PHP, Google App Engine and Cloud SQL. Thanks for any input!

Answer (score 0):

You could very well count how many users you have, then run a `for()` loop on every database and update the necessary table. Not sure how efficient or kosher this is in terms of professional development, but it'd make sense to me to do something like this:

```
function UpdateDatabase($db_name) {
// connect to database here
// run query (queries) to update the database here
}

for($user = number_of_users; $user = 1; $user++) {
UpdateDatabase("Subscriber_" . $user);
}
```

Of course, this code is assuming that you number it numerically. However you number or list all your users, the idea is the same. The `for` loop will do something like this:

- Gets to user #id
- Update the database "Subscriber_id"

So, as it loops through, it will start from the user with id 1 and go all the way to the end.